# Proplem with oj-button (oracle jet button)

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

Why oj-button concatenate its label text to itself when we keep clicking on it,

here is an example of the button in this cookbook button (try when keep click on it) :
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=pushButtons&demo=events

so on keep clicking the label will be: Button Action 1Button Action 1
and Button Action 1Button Action 1Button Action 1 and so on ?!!
[image: image for the buttons]

Answer (score 1):

That might be a bug either on the Oracle Jet site, or script error on your browser. Because it is not concatenating now.
It is perfectly working as expected.